# Is it possible to determine whether an object is of a class type or not using a trait through a non-type template parameter in C++20?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++20, compiler-bug, non-type-template-parameter

Consider this code:

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct wrapper {
    T& ref;
    constexpr wrapper(T& ref) : ref(ref) {}
};

// Trait that checks whether a type is of the form `wrapper<T>`
template <typename T>
struct is_wrapper_type : std::false_type {};

template <typename T>
struct is_wrapper_type<wrapper<T>> : std::true_type {};

// Trait that checks whether an object is of the type `wrapper<T>`
template <auto& Value>
struct is_wrapper_object;

template <auto& Value>
    requires (!is_wrapper_type<std::decay_t<decltype(Value)>>::value)
struct is_wrapper_object<Value> : std::false_type {};

template <auto& Value>
    requires is_wrapper_type<std::decay_t<decltype(Value)>>::value
struct is_wrapper_object<Value> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    static constexpr int v = 42;
    static_assert(!is_wrapper_object<v>::value);
    static constexpr wrapper w {v};
    static_assert(is_wrapper_object<w>::value);
}
```

The above [fails to compile in Clang with the errors shown below but compiles successfully in GCC](https://godbolt.org/z/n3ozovd67).

```
<source>:30:20: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'is_wrapper_object<v>'
   30 |     static_assert(!is_wrapper_object<v>::value);
      |                    ^
<source>:18:8: note: template is declared here
   18 | struct is_wrapper_object;
      |        ^
<source>:32:19: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'is_wrapper_object<w>'
   32 |     static_assert(is_wrapper_object<w>::value);
      |                   ^
<source>:18:8: note: template is declared here
   18 | struct is_wrapper_object;
      |        ^
```

Which compiler is correct here?

I believe GCC should be correct here as the above code *should* be legal on paper, however, I am not sure whether that is really the case.

Moreover, if I change the definition of the trait `is_wrapper_object` to this:

```cpp
template <auto& Value>
struct is_wrapper_object : std::false_type {};

template <auto& Value>
    requires is_wrapper_type<std::decay_t<decltype(Value)>>::value
struct is_wrapper_object<Value> : std::true_type {};
```

It [compiles on Clang as well, albeit with wrong output](https://godbolt.org/z/Yxax4xEzY).

Comment: This trait seems to be unnecessary complex. ¿Why don't you use something like `template<auto& Value> using is_wrapper_object = is_wrapper_type<std::decay_t<decltype(Value)>>;`?

Comment: Essentially it can be simplified to this: https://godbolt.org/z/hcT49EWff

Comment: @user7860670 Sure, that would make the example above compile on both compilers. However, my actual question is *why* the code in the question fails to compile under Clang and that whether it is a compiler bug or not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GCC is correct.

Note that simply replacing your `auto&` with `const auto&` makes the code compile for both. Whatever the issue is, it has something to do with placeholder type specifiers in partial specializations.

Note that:

> If the type `T` of a [template-parameter](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#nt:template-parameter) contains a [placeholder type](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.spec.auto) or a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]), the type of the parameter is the type deduced for the variable `x` in the invented declaration
>
> ```cpp
> T x = E ;
> ```

- [[temp.arg.nontype] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/temp.arg.nontype#1)

In other words, `auto&` in a template parameter should be `const int&` and `const wrapper&` after such deduction.
It should not be necessary for the user to provide `const` themselves.

I was unable to find a relevant LLVM bug report, so I have submitted one: [LLVM Bug 77189](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/77189).

#### Minimal Reproducible Example

See https://godbolt.org/z/rhKsWKdPz

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <auto& Value, int>
struct test : std::false_type {};

template <auto& Value>
struct test<Value, 0> : std::true_type {};

int main() {
    static constexpr int v = 42;
    static_assert(test<v, 0>::value); // fails for clang
}
```

From this, we can tell that clang is *completely* unable to deduce `Value` within the partial specialization of `test`.